# How can I check if the parent firm is in the same city of the subsidiaries?

Tags: r

I'm a beginner with spatial statistics and I'm not sure how to generalize the question.

But I have the structure:

```
firm <- c(11212, 11212,11212,11212, 2632, 2632, 3552, 4218, 536, 6667, 6667, 6667, 7278, 7278)
id_p_s <- c(1, 2, 2,2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2)
city <- c("PITIMBU", "ALHANDRA","ALHANDRA","ALHANDRA" "CARUARU", "BREJO DA MADRE DE DEUS",
               "GUARAPUAVA", "ARAPIRACA", "FEIRA DE SANTANA", "GUARAPUAVA",
               "GUARAPUAVA", "MOGI DAS CRUZES", "PIRACICABA", "PIRACICABA")
enterprises <- data.frame(firm = firm, id_p_s = id_p_s,
                       city = city)
```

If the firm is a parent, then `id_p_s==1` otherwise is `2`. How can I check if the parent firm is in the same city of one of his subsidiaries?

Just to know, every firm has 1 parent and can have 0, 1 or more subsidiaries.

I have been trying to use a `group_by` and `filter` with `tidyverse`, but I can't get a good way to view this information. After that, I will calculate the distance from the parent to subsidiaries and within subsidiaries.

I thought about something like this:

```r
 firm             city             amout_of_firms       include_parent

 11212          PITIMBU                    1                F
 11212          ALHANDRA                   3                F  
 2632           CARUARU                    1                F
 2632           BREJO DA MADRE DE DEUS     1                F
 3552           GUARAPUAVA                 1                F
 4218           ARAPIRACA                  1                F
 536            FEIRA DE SANTANA           1                F
 6667           GUARAPUAVA                 2                T
 6667           MOGI DAS CRUZES            1                F
 7278           PIRACICABA                 2                T
```

So I can filter `include_parent==T` and find witch firm have the parent and one or more subsidiaries in the same city.

Comment: What do you mean by "company is a matrix"?

Comment: You have not clearly defined your question.  Who matrix?  How is city related to matrix?  How can the company variable have more than one company with the same name?

Comment: @jsb and Gray . sorry I translated wrong. Is more clear this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every `firm` and `city` you can count number of rows in it and check if `id_p_s` has both values 1 and 2 in it.

```
library(dplyr)

enterprises %>%
  group_by(firm, city) %>%
  summarise(amount_of_firms = n(), 
            include_parent = all(1:2 %in% id_p_s))

#    firm city                   amount_of_firms include_parent
#   <dbl> <chr>                            <int> <lgl>         
# 1   536 FEIRA DE SANTANA                     1 FALSE         
# 2  2632 BREJO DA MADRE DE DEUS               1 FALSE         
# 3  2632 CARUARU                              1 FALSE         
# 4  3552 GUARAPUAVA                           1 FALSE         
# 5  4218 ARAPIRACA                            1 FALSE         
# 6  6667 GUARAPUAVA                           2 TRUE          
# 7  6667 MOGI DAS CRUZES                      1 FALSE         
# 8  7278 PIRACICABA                           2 TRUE          
# 9 11212 ALHANDRA                             3 FALSE         
#10 11212 PITIMBU                              1 FALSE
```

Equivalent in `data.table` would be :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(enterprises)[, .(amount_of_firms = .N, 
                       include_parent = all(1:2 %in% id_p_s)), .(firm, city)]
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't know the function `all()`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are after

```
> aggregate(company ~.,enterprises,list)
   id_m_s                   city company
1       2               ALHANDRA       1
2       1              ARAPIRACA       4
3       2 BREJO DA MADRE DE DEUS       2
4       1                CARUARU       2
5       1       FEIRA DE SANTANA       5
6       1             GUARAPUAVA    3, 6
7       2             GUARAPUAVA       6
8       2        MOGI DAS CRUZES       6
9       1             PIRACICABA       7
10      2             PIRACICABA       7
11      1                PITIMBU       1
```